# Cannot connect to MongoDB via node.js in Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My node.js express app cannot connect to the MongoDB in a Docker. *I'm not that familiar with Docker.*

node.js connection:

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
...
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', ... );
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:argon
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: “2”
 services:
  web:
   build: .
   volumes:
     — ./:/app
   ports:
   — “3000:3000”
   links:
    — mongo
   mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      — “27017:27017”
```

Build command: `docker build -t NAME .`

Run command: `docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 NAME`

Connection error:

```
[MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]'
```

Comment: DId you change the `bind_ip` in the MongoDB config in it's container? If not then it is only listening on localhost to that container only.

Comment: what would be that @NeilLunn?

Comment: I didnt set any MongoDB config file btw... @NeilLunn

Comment: It will be in `/etc/mongod.conf` by default. You would need to bind to `0.0.0.0` in order to listen on "all" external interfaces. In depth "docker" config is not really my thing either, but you appear to be using a more "legacy" mode of "linking". And the documentation seems to suggest ["Docker Networks"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) as the preferred method for exposing ports between containers

Comment: For me it simply worked: "docker run --network=host myapp:1.0", .. my app was connected to a wrong network .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017', ... );
```

Change your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:

  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

And use some [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) commands:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d mongo
docker-compose up web
```

Comment: didnt work: `docker-compose up -d mongo
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 10`

Comment: I think you need to change the docker-compose.

Comment: Please, see my new answer. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: got this error: `Recreating test_web_1 ... 
Recreating test_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for test_web_1  no such image: sha256:2b0195350ef188fa3ca4fc41f3670fa1b7650ab0bd2cde74e5a0b6c95193c55b: No such image: sha256:2b0195350ef188fa3ca4fc41f3670fa1b7650ab0bd2cde74e5a0b6c95193c55b

ERROR: for web  no such image: sha256:2b0195350ef188fa3ca4fc41f3670fa1b7650ab0bd2cde74e5a0b6c95193c55b: No such image: sha256:2b0195350ef188fa3ca4fc41f3670fa1b7650ab0bd2cde74e5a0b6c95193c55b`

Comment: Try `docker compose build`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148459/discussion-between-nano-galvao-and-marcelo-filho).

Comment: I tried this out since I was getting errors connecting to mongo on my local machine and it works perfectly fine. Want to udnerstand where is this db? Is the data persistent after I stop the container?

Answer (score 9):

Try this.

1. When using linked docker containers you should use the name of the container in this case for example your connection to mongodb should be `mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017', ... );` instead of `mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', ... );`. The reason for changing it to mongo is because you used the links attribute to mongo in your `docker-compose.yml`. That would result to a hostname of  mongo in your `/etc/hosts` of the web docker container. Reference [linking-containers](https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb).
2. The docker-compose.yml seems to be lacking an indention. On the mongo attribute should be the same level as web.

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:
     web:
      build: .
      volumes: ['./:/app']
      ports: [ '3000:3000' ]
      links: [ mongo ]
     mongo:
      image: mongo
      ports: [ '27017:27017' ]
   ```
3. I tried your configuration using my docker what Ive done is update `docker-compose.yml` then I `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up`. [Logs of my local run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDH4d.png)

Comment: ive updated the question, is the same but with the `mongo`

Comment: Why is still connecting to `localhost:27017` ? It should be `mongo:27017` if you have changed the connection from node.js to mongodb. In your node.js file it should be `mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017', ... );`

Comment: @MarceloFilho have you run just `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Okay. Can you check in `/etc/hosts` of the web container if the IP of the mongo is added? Also what is the output of `docker ps`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still have this question, but the `datasources.json` should be:

```
"host": "mongo"
```

rather than "localhost".

In my logs I see:

```
mongo    |  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.3:47880 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

As you can see, docker compose will NAT mongo to another V-LAN. The IP address `172.22.0.0` is an internal IP address used by the daemon to route a `docker-compose` image. So `localhost` is now not in the game.

At least, it works for me.

`datasources.json`

```
"mongoDS": {
    "host": "mongo",
    "port": 27017,
```

...

Answer (score 0):

in my case works like this :

just link to the container from the command line. db is my up database container

**sudo docker run -it --link db:db1 --publish 4000-4006:4000-4006 --name backend backend:latest**