# Node container not able to connect to mongo container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize a `node` application that I have which uses a `mongodb` instance. I am trying to point it to `'mongodb://mongo:27018/eugenie_cp'` but it keeps going to `127.0.0.1:27017`

I have followed these two questions likely to be marked duplicate with but I have already used the answers from there:

[Cannot connect to MongoDB via node.js in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938344/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-via-node-js-in-docker)

[MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011552/mongodb-on-with-docker-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-c?rq=1)

I am getting the error due to the following line, but I am not able to solve it.

```
// call express middleware
var express = require('express');
//Initialize the app.
var app = express();

//setting the mongoose options.
var options = {
    useMongoClient: true,
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            socketTimeoutMS: 0,
            connectTimeout: 0
        }
    },
    server: {
        reconnectTries: 1000
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            socketTimeoutMS: 0,
            connectTimeout: 0
        }
    }
};

// Mongo instance here.
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// setting the MongoDb connection URL / string
var mongodb_connection_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/eugenie_cp';
// connect to our database
mongoose.connect(mongodb_connection_url, options);

// MongoDb connection error check
var db_check = mongoose.connection;
db_check.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

I get the following error:

```
app      | MongoDB connection error: Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
app      |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14) {
app      |   name: 'MongoError',
app      |   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'
app      | }]
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3002:3002"
        links:
            - mongo
    mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo:3.2
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27018:27017"
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: The error does not match the node.js code that you have shown. Please check if you are executing right code.

Comment: @michalk I have updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docker linking or docker-compose network you should not use publish port, in service to service communication you must use expose port or another word container port, not the host port.

So update the connection string.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongodb_connection_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/eugenie_cp';
mongoose.connect(mongodb_connection_url, options);
```

#### EDIT:

Major problem was due to the code being cached. We tested with a simple `.js` program to test the connection, which pointed to the right location finally, and gave us the idea that the code wasn't being refreshed.
I guess, cache invalidation is one of the big computer problems.

Started mongo first

```
$ docker-compose up --build -d mongo
$ docker-compose up --build -d app
```

And it worked.

Comment: I made the change, and then `docker build -t cpde_eugenie .` and `docker-compose up`, but I still get the same error. I updated it in the question as well

Comment: are you sure the mongo container is running? what is the logs of docker-compose logs?

Comment: also is there any database? you did not pass DB name and user name? `      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example`

Comment: It says `Listening on 0.0.0.0` and `waiting for connections on port 27017`

Comment: also remove ` links  - mongo` docker-compose already create network for u

Comment: Access control is not enabled for the database.

Comment: from the error it seems it not picking the new code? try to build `docker build --no-cache -t cpde_eugenie .`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200855/discussion-between-adiii-and-pissall).